# Painting window buttons over ribbon control

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

I would like to achieve a similar look and feel as in MS OFfice. I implemented ribbon control with some problems.

**My first question :** As seen on the picture, I think MS Office uses a borderless form/window and "paints" the minimize/mazimize/close buttons on top of Ribbon Control. (I am not sure I simply guessed from the memories of old days.) How can I do this or something similar to achieve something as MS Office.

**My Second Question :** I am doing wrong something but don't know what. I added the ribbon control but couldn't add the images as seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbon%28v=vs.110%29). When I use the below code it doesn't throw an error at design time. (If I change file name it throws an error at design time saying that there was no file like that.)

```
<RibbonButton x:Name="QATButton2" SmallImageSource="Resources/b.bmp" />
```

But it throws this error at run-time.

`'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '28' and line position '35'.`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is using [RibbonWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbonwindow%28v=vs.110%29) instead of Window.

Answer (score 1):

That exception should have an `InnerException` property that you can look at to see the root cause of the problem. I would drill down into that in Visual Studio.